# Carrierwave : How to trigger images are processed after running recreate_versions! method

Tags: ruby-on-rails, carrierwave

I am uploading the images using CarrierWave gem and it is creating image url like
domain/images/5/images.jpg and after running the recreate_versions!, it is changing image url to domain/images/5/secure_token.jpg.

It is renaming images.jpg to "#{secure_token}".jpg. I don't have track of original filename.

So How can I trigger the images are processed or not.

Thank you in advance.